# Paypal REST API in Java - getAccessToken returns null

Tags: api, paypal

I am trying to setup paypal API. however the getAccessToken() method returns null. when looking at the API it mentioned to use either Payment.initConfig or by creating OAuthTokenCredentials. both ways the accessToken is returned as null.

```
public static void createPayment() {
    String clientID = "xxxxxx"
    String clientSecret = "xxxxx";
    String paymentID = null;
    OAuthTokenCredential credentials;
    String accessToken;
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        prop.setProperty("service.Endpoint", "http://api.sandbox.paypal.com");
        prop.setProperty("clientID", clientID);
        prop.setProperty("clientSecret", clientSecret);

        prop.setProperty("http.GoogleAppEngine", "false");
        prop.setProperty("http.UseProxy", "false");

        prop.setProperty("http.ConnectionTimeOut", "5000");
        prop.setProperty("http.Retry", "1");
        prop.setProperty("http.ReadTimeOut", "30000");
        prop.setProperty("http.MaxConnection", "100");

        //tried this way. 
        credentials = Payment.initConfig(prop);

        //also tried this way.
        //accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret).getAccessToken();

        accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();
        Payment.get(accessToken, paymentID);
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setIntent("sale");
        payment.create(apiContext);            
    } catch (PayPalRESTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PayPal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before call "getAccessToken", you have to configure the Endpoint:

```
    // Sandbox (for testing) : https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
    // Live (production) : https://api.paypal.com

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("service.EndPoint", "https://api.paypal.com");
    ConfigManager.getInstance().load(properties);

    OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    String accessToken = tokenCredential.getAccessToken();
```

More information at: [PayPal-Java-SDK / GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK)

Answer (score 0):

Get default properties from "sdk_config.properties" 
Available at PayPal GitHub: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK
If needed, add or modify any properties and then :

```
Payment.initConfig(properties);
OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently created the instructions to use PayPal Java SDK. You can read them about it here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call

Using [PayPal-Java-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK), you do not need to create access token separately. Instead you create an `APIContext` object, and pass your clientId, secret, and mode(sandbox/live). You pass this instance to all the API operations, and SDK will automatically call the oauth, and get the access token. This also improves performance by caching the access token and re-using it for later use. This only should reduce number of network calls to half.

Here is how the code would look like:

```
APIContext context = new APIContext(clientId, clientSecret, "sandbox");

Payment payment = new Payment();
// Fill in all the details.
payment.create(context);
```

Here is the wiki page explaining that: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call